# Undefined reference to sasl_x when build

Tags: c, makefile, apache-kafka, libraries, pkg-config

I'm trying to compile my program with gcc using the librdkafka library,

I receive this kind of error undefined reference to sasl_something

> //usr/local/lib/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o): In function `rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_close':
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:409: undefined reference to`sasl_dispose'
>   //usr/local/lib/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o): In function `rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_recv':
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:74: undefined reference to`sasl_client_step'
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:100: undefined reference to `sasl_errdetail'
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:112: undefined reference to`sasl_getprop'
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:116: undefined reference to `sasl_getprop'
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:120: undefined reference to`sasl_getprop'
>   //usr/local/lib/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o): In function `rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_client_new':
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:462: undefined reference to`sasl_client_new'
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:484: undefined reference to `sasl_client_start'
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:502: undefined reference to`sasl_errdetail'
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:473: undefined reference to `sasl_listmech'
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:466: undefined reference to`sasl_errstring'
>   //usr/local/lib/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o): In function `rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_global_init':
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:604: undefined reference to`sasl_client_init'
>   /home/ilan/librdkafka-master/src/rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c:606: undefined reference to `sasl_errstring'

My makefile looks like this

> LIBS = -L ../utils -lutils -L ../network -lnetwork -Wl,-Bstatic -lev -ljansson -lmpdec -lrdkafka -lrdkafka++ -lz -llz4 -lssl -lcrypto -lhiredis -Wl,-Bdynamic -lm -lpthread -ldl -lcurl -lstdc++

I'm sure there is something up with the libraries but cannot figure out what exactly,

Maybe using pkg-config rdkafka would resolve the issue, but I don't know how to use it here.

Can you please advise ?

Comment: Symbols from cyrus-sasl library are unknown. Adding -lsasl2 should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it resolve the issue, but it creates another one `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.a(otp.o): In function 'bin2hex':
(.text+0xbf0): multiple definition of 'bin2hex'
../utils/libutils.a(ut_misc.o):/home/ilan/program-master/utils/ut_misc.c:181: first defined here`  It is much longer, but it is that kind of issue

Comment: I am writing more elaborate answer to your initial question. 

Is it possible that you have your own implementation of bin2hex function in /home/ilan/program-master/utils/ut_misc.c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cyryus SASL](http://cyrusimap.org/sasl/) is not linked. Library is usually named sasl2, so adding *-lsasl2* should fix the problem.

I just installed rdkafka on my system (Gentoo Linux) and its pkg-config file contains -lsasl2. So yes. Using pkg-config should solve described problem too.

See how to use pkg-config in makefile [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271087/pkg-config-output-not-working-with-makefile#271142).

To get also private libraries use:

```
LDFLAGS  += `pkg-config rdkafka --libs --static`
```

Comment: Thanks but how do you use pkg-config in the makefile ?

Comment: I receive this error when using -lsasl2 : `/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.a(otp.o): In function 'bin2hex': (.text+0xbf0): multiple definition of 'bin2hex' ../utils/libutils.a(ut_misc.o):/home/ilan/program-master/utils/ut_misc.c:181: first defined here`

Comment: Answer improved. I have seen your previous comment about bin2hex.  It looks to me like another function named bin2hex is already defined in /home/ilan/program-master/utils/ut_misc.c:181. If it is your own implementation of bin2hex try renaming it.

Comment: I think that my real issue is that I don't have cyrus sasl installed in the first place, but reading their installation guide, I think I don't have enough level to complete it... I have compilation errors already with them.

Comment: It is quite common package. Probably it can be installed with package manager.

Comment: Like this one ? sudo apt-get install sasl2-bin ? On their website it seems to be much complex

Comment: I think it is libsasl2-2.