# Golang Apache Kafka ConfluentInc not building on MacOS

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-go

I am facing issues with building the binary file for my inventory microservice when using Kafka consumer from `github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka` on my Mac M1. Initially, I set `CGO_ENABLED=0` to disable the use of C but now it is set to `CGO_ENABLED=1` because that Kafka Go module works with C code. I am also using docker compose to spin up containers on Docker Desktop. The following is the error message I am getting when building the binary for my microservice:

```
cd ../inventory-service && env CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o inventoryApp ./cmd/api
# runtime/cgo
linux_syscall.c:67:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'setresgid' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
linux_syscall.c:67:13: note: did you mean 'setregid'?
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:593:6: note: 'setregid' declared here
linux_syscall.c:73:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'setresuid' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
linux_syscall.c:73:13: note: did you mean 'setreuid'?
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:595:6: note: 'setreuid' declared here
make: *** [build_inventory] Error 2
```

#### When `CGO_ENABLED=0`, I get this error message:

```
cd ../inventory-service && env CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o inventoryApp ./cmd/api
internal/kafka/consumer.go:4:2: imported and not used: "log"
internal/kafka/consumer.go:9:78: undefined: kafka.Consumer
internal/kafka/consumer.go:11:25: undefined: kafka.NewConsumer
internal/kafka/consumer.go:11:44: undefined: kafka.ConfigMap
internal/kafka/consumer.go:28:57: undefined: kafka.Consumer
make: *** [build_inventory] Error 2
```

#### `Makefile`

```
build_inventory:
    @echo "Build inventory binary..."
    cd ../inventory-service && env CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o ${INVENTORY_BINARY} ./cmd/api
```

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
  inventory-service:
    build:
      context: ./../inventory-service
      dockerfile: ./../inventory-service/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      inventory-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8002:8002'
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: inventory-mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_HOST: inventory-mysql
      MYSQL_PORT: '3306'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: imsdb
      SERVICE_PORT: '8002'

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    ports:
      # To learn about configuring Kafka for access across networks, see
      # https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
      - '9092:9092'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

#### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN mkdir /app

COPY inventoryApp /app

CMD ["/app/inventoryApp"]
```

### Update

This is my new Dockerfile but I am facing other issues.

```
FROM golang:1.20.4-alpine3.17 AS builder

RUN set -ex &&\
    apk add --no-progress --no-cache \
      gcc \
      musl-dev

ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=arm64

RUN apk add --no-progress --no-cache gcc musl-dev

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# install dependencies
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -tags musl -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o inventoryApp ./cmd/api

FROM scratch

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/inventoryApp .

CMD ["./inventoryApp"]
```

Errors:

```
16.94 /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_arm64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_musl_linux_arm64.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o): in function `rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_close':
16.94 (.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `sasl_dispose'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_musl_linux_arm64.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o): in function `rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_recv':
16.94 (.text+0x198): undefined reference to `sasl_client_step'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `sasl_errdetail'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0x354): undefined reference to `sasl_getprop'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0x384): undefined reference to `sasl_getprop'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0x3a4): undefined reference to `sasl_getprop'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_musl_linux_arm64.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o): in function `rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_client_new':
16.94 (.text+0xf64): undefined reference to `sasl_client_new'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0xfc4): undefined reference to `sasl_client_start'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0xfe4): undefined reference to `sasl_errdetail'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0x10fc): undefined reference to `sasl_listmech'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0x1170): undefined reference to `sasl_errstring'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_musl_linux_arm64.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o): in function `rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_global_init':
16.94 (.text+0x16cc): undefined reference to `sasl_client_init'
16.94 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0x16fc): undefined reference to `sasl_errstring'
16.94 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
16.94
```

Comment: As per [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/54695) "You are cross-compiling from Darwin to Linux with CGO_ENABLED=1. That requires setting CC to a cross-compiler that generates Linux objects using Linux header files.". Simplest solution is probably to add a [build stage](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/) in your `Dockerfile` instead of cross-compiling.

Comment: Hey, do you mean building in Dockerfile instead of Makefile?

Comment: Correct, you could get this working by installing the correct compiler/libraries, but building under docker is probably simplier (and removes the need to update another compiler etc).

Comment: @Brits I have updated my Dockerfile but I am currently facing new issues as shown in the picture above. I am using Mac M1 on arm64 architecture.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49463975/11810946) or [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/981#issuecomment-1821445466) help? (sorry don't have a Mac available to replicate this).

Comment: @Brits Hey Brits, I have decided to switch to `segmentio/kafka-go` to avoid the complexities of cross-compilation with the C library. Thanks for the help anyways! It is working fine now with this go module.

Comment: No worries - relying on C libraries can be a bit painful! Great to hear you have a solution.